# Composition of almost-everywhere differentiable functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $g, f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are almost-everywhere differentiable. Is $g \circ f$ almost-everywhere differentiable?

([This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329463/composition-of-almost-everywhere-continuous-functions-mathbbr-rightarrow-mat) deals with a-e. continuity, but the answer does not apply.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333004/composition-of-almost-everywhere-differentiable-functions) deals with a-e. differentiability but in higher dimensions; the answers do not apply either.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exist almost everywhere differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ such that $g\circ f$ is not measurable. One example is given in [Ciesielski et al. - $\mathcal{I}$-Density Continuous Functions](https://books.google.nl/books?id=u4jUCQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=104&f=false) on page 104. Their construction is as follows:

> Consider a perfect nowhere dense set $P\subset\mathbb{R}$ and a nonmeasurable set $S\subset P$. Let $f$ be a homeomorphism s.t. $f^{-1}(C)=P$, where $C$ is a Cantor set of measure $0$, and let $g=1_S\circ f^{-1}$. Then $f$ is a.e. differentiable as a homeomorphism, and $g$ is a.e. differentiable because $g=1_{f(S)}$ and $f(S)\subset C$ has measure $0$. However, $g\circ f=1_S$ is not measurable.